# Removing outliers from a grey-scale image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, kinect, grayscale

## Question

I have an images sequence representing depth information which I'd like to clean.
There are some outliers (values with intensity below 25, for a 0-255 range) which I would like to be filled with an acceptable alternative (an average value localised to that specific area could be a good guess).

Can someone see a simple way to do this? I've tried to use a median filter (filter size of 10) substituting the undesired values with NaN, but it did worsen the situation, which improves instead by substituting them with a general average value.

[image: Basic trial]

P.S. Someone has already suggested me to use a *fast wavelet reconstruction*, but I would not really know where to start...

## Implemented solution (so far)

The solution I implemented (before reading about `inpaint_nans` suggested by [**tmpearce**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1214731/tmpearce)) is:

1. duplicate the original image;
2. filling the invalid pixels with a general average value;
3. use a circular disk of ray 10 for blurring it;
4. replacing the invalid values in the original image with what I got from point 3.
5. run a median filter of size 10.

```
img2 = img;                                       
img2(img < .005) = mean(img(:));                  
H = fspecial('disk',10);                          
img3 = imfilter(img2,H,'symmetric');              
img4 = img;                                       
img4(img < .3) = img3(img < .3);                  
filterSize = 10;                                  
padopt = {'zeros','indexed','symmetric'};         
IMG = medfilt2(img4, [1 1]*filterSize, padopt{p});
```

[image: Second trial]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend the [inpaint_nans](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4551) contribution from the `MATLAB File Exchange` - start as you've already done by replacing outliers with `NaN` and use the link to go from there.

From the description of the function:

> Interpolate NaN elements in a 2-d array using non-NaN elements. Can
>   also extrapolate, as it does not use a triangulation of the data.
>   Inpaint_nans offers several different approaches to the interpolation,
>   which give tradeoffs in accuracy versus speed and memory required. All
>   the methods currently found in inpaint_nans are based on sparse linear
>   algebra and PDE discretizations. In essence, a PDE is solved to be
>   consistent with the information supplied.

Hooray for reusable code!

Comment: my thoughts exactly, only 20 seconds too late. +1

Answer (score 4):

Use a function called `roifill`. You need to mess with it a little bit. I had to use `imdilate` because it interpolates from the boundary.

Code:

```
testimage = imread('BAPz5.png');
testimage = double(rgb2gray(testimage));
testimage_filt = roifill(testimage,imdilate(testimage<100,true(4)));
figure(1);
subplot(1,2,1);
imshow(testimage,[]);
subplot(1,2,2);
imshow(testimage_filt,[]);
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The post is answered but just for the record, in [1], the author based on a basic principle of natural shapes, i.e., the objects follow a second order smoothness, he suggests an in-painting method that minimize curvature in a
least-squares sense. He also offers [code](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~barron/). Good luck.

[1] Α Categoty-Level 3-D Object Database: Putting the kineckto Work (ICCV)

[image]

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks **Darkmoor** for your note! It's always nice to get someone else opinion, supported by a paper!